# Measuring the height of a box

Tags: calculations, height, unit-of-measure, calc

Solution in Edit 3. It works well, but seems to need an optimization. `:)`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newcommand{\Title}[1]{
   \newlength\tbheight
   \setlength{\tbheight}{\heightof{\phantom{\fontsize{0.04\textheight}   {0.04\textheight}\selectfont \parbox{\titlewidth\textwidth}{\textbf{#1}}\par}}}
%\setlength{\headheight}{\tbheight + 0.055\textwidth}
}

%it should not matter if I use:
\Title{A longer Text that goes over two or maybe three lines}
\begin{document}
%or I use it in this place:
%\Title{A longer Text that goes over two or maybe three lines}
\end{document}
```

This was suggested to work on some threads. But it dont. 
I want to measure the height the manipulated input. My own idea was: manipulate the input, make it invisible, put it in a box, let the box grow by text, measure the height of the box. This sounds easy, but I guess, my skills aren't grown enough.

Got anyone a nice idea for solving this?

## Edit:

If I use this code, I do not get any error:

```
\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\title{#1}
\def\tbheight{\heightof{\vphantom{\fontsize{0.04\textheight}{0.04\textheight}\selectfont \parbox{\titlewidth\textwidth}{\textbf{#1}}\par}}}
\setlength{\headheight}{ 0.055\textheight}
}
```

but if I do so

```
\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\title{#1}
    \def\tbheight{\heightof{\vphantom{\fontsize{0.04\textheight}{0.04\textheight}\selectfont \parbox{\titlewidth\textwidth}{\textbf{#1}}\par}}}
    \setlength{\headheight}{\tbheight + 0.055\textheight}
    }
```

there are 6.

Error 1 Paragraph ended before \calc@textsize was complete.
I guess to solve this, there is another command required?

Error
2-4 to many '{' or forgotten endgroup
5,6 missing number, illegal unit

## Edit 2:

If I use this Code, I don't have any errors, but this measures wrong.

```
\newcommand{\temp}{}
\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\title{#1}
        \renewcommand\temp{\parbox{\titlewidth\textwidth}{\fontsize{0.04\textheight}{0.04\textheight}\selectfont \textbf{Titelmasterformat durch Klicken bearbeiten}\par}}
        \newlength{\tbheight}
        \settoheight\tbheight{\heightof{\temp}}

        \renewcommand{\temp}{\parbox[c][0.055\textheight]{1pt}{$_{}$}}
        \newlength\headspace
        \settoheight\headspace{\temp}

    \setlength{\headheight}{\tbheight + \headspace}
}
```

When I type in \the\textheight the output is

> 3383.03267
>   if I multiply it by 0.055 it is
>   3383.03267 * 0.055 ~ 186
>   but
>   \the\headspace ~ 100

## Edit 3:

If I use `\settototalheight` instead of `\settoheight`, I've got the right measures, but something went wrong. It is not the "height", as I guessed.

```
\newcommand{\temp}{}
    \newcommand{\Title}[1]{\title{#1}
            \renewcommand\temp{\parbox{\titlewidth\textwidth}{\fontsize{0.04\textheight}{0.04\textheight}\selectfont \textbf{Titelmasterformat durch Klicken bearbeiten}\par}}
        \newlength{\tbheight}
        \settototalheight\tbheight{\temp}

        \renewcommand{\temp}{\parbox[c][0.055\textheight]{1pt}{$_{}$}}
        \newlength\headspace
        \settoheight\headspace{\temp}

    \setlength{\headheight}{\tbheight + \headspace}
}
```

Comment: What's the `\phantom` for?

Comment: it makes the text besides invisible and inserts a box of height and width of that text. You could use "vphantom" for a vertical-phantom, with 0 width, and "hphantom" for an horizontal-phantom with 0 height.

Comment: Do you know about `\settoheight`?

Comment: I used it in my last edit ^^

Comment: but \settoheight measures wrong. If I setup an fbox{parbox} with height "0.055\textheight" and one of height "\headspace" I get two different boxes.

Comment: `\settoheight{\tbheight}{text}`; no `\heightof`. It would be easier if you explained what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ah, I saw the fault you pointed out. But I used "\settototalheight" in reason of the "parbox".

Comment: If you only use the box to measure it the `\phantom` is not doing anything useful at all, but it is very hard to work out what you are wanting to measure.

Comment: you are setting the font size to a fraction of textheight? That's not exactly an error but it is _very_ weird, I don't think I've seen anyone do that in 30 years of tex use, what is the intended use here?

Comment: If you use `\temp`  defined as `\renewcommand{\temp}{\parbox[c][0.055\textheight]{1pt}{$_{}$}}` you get a vertically centred parbox so its height is more or less half its total height+depth but why are you making a parbox here at all, don't you just want some proportion of `\textheight`???

Comment: I'm going to setup a class, that will do some steps: 1. You can choose between a0 to a4paper, and this gets you the measure for all other elements on the page. 2. There is a title, which will be printed on all chosen paper-sizes equal, as well as the whole header, footer and text-body. You don't have to use any option to fit the letter-size to the chosen document. It's just for a "homework" nothing for public.

Comment: Not really. The inner text will depend on the \textheight. Therefore this input depends on the chosen a0 to a4paper. I guess, there is something quite better method :) I guess, there is no "\paperheight" command by default? If I try, it turns out not.

Comment: \meaning\titlewidth gave me "undefined"

Comment: `\paperheight` is defined in the latex format so yes it is defined in all latex documents so I don't understand your comment above but you have still given no indication of what you are trying to measure, just posted fragments of code that make boxes of various strange sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a savebox in the preamble and use it (multiple times) in the body.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newsavebox{\titlebox}

\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\savebox{\titlebox}%
  {\selectfont \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\fontsize{0.04\textheight}{0.05\textheight}\textbf{#1}}}%
}

\Title{A longer Text that goes over two or maybe three lines}
\begin{document}
height = \the\ht\titlebox\par
depth = \the\dp\titlebox\par
total = \the\dimexpr \ht\titlebox+\dp\titlebox\relax\par
width = \the\wd\titlebox

\usebox{\titlebox}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Very useful the TeX commands `\the\ht`, `\the\dp`, and `\the\wd` to know the dimensions of a saved box. Until now I had used the LaTeX variant `\settowidth{\mylength}{\usebox{\mybox}} \the\mylength`: quite an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you want to achieve. Anyway, here's the code.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\newlength\tbheight % should be outside
\newcommand{\titlewidth}{0.3} % ???

\newcommand{\Title}[1]{% <-- don't forget
   \settoheight{\tbheight}{%
     \parbox[b]{\titlewidth\textwidth}{%
       \fontsize{0.04\textheight}{0.04\textheight}\selectfont
       \bfseries #1
     }%
   }%
}

%it should not matter if I use:
\normalfont
\Title{A longer Text that goes over two or maybe three lines}
\edef\THETBHEIGHT{\the\tbheight} % just to save the set value
\begin{document}
%or I use it in this place:
\Title{A longer Text that goes over two or maybe three lines}

\THETBHEIGHT

\the\tbheight

\end{document}
```

Note that typesetting text in the preamble is not guaranteed to give meaningful results; here I used `\normalfont`, but in general it's better to delay such things at begin document.

I used `\settoheight` and `\parbox[b]`, so the height measures the whole box, except for the depth of the last line, which should be ignored anyway.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to save "\textheight" in a variable, without editing it, while compiling? If I do \def\Textheight{\textheight} and \setlength\textheight{.8\textheight} the resut will be: \Textheight = \textheight.

Comment: @Shalec `\newlength\Textheight\setlength\Textheight{\textheight}`  will save the original value of `\textheight` in `\Textheight`